# Ajax запрос node js + express + vue

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, vue.js, axios

Пытаюсь отправить get запрос с клиента на сервер, чтобы в дальнейшем забрать необходимые данные из БД. Для  XMLHttpRequests использую библиотеку axios. Проблема в том, что запрос не отправляется, консоль выводит: GET http:// localhost:3000/ items 404 (Not Found). Error: Request failed with status code 404. В чем может быть ошибка?

```
Клиентская часть:
<script>
  export default {
    data(){
        return{
            items: []
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        this.fetchItems();
    },
    methods: {
        fetchItems (){
           let uri = '/items';
           this.axios.get(uri).then((response) => {
                this.items = response.data.items;
            });
        }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Серверная часть:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var itemRoutes = express.Router();

itemRoutes.route('/items').get(function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to the homepage');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Если сервер и клиент находятся на разных портах, то при обращении с клиента на сервер в пути нужно указывать полностью путь с портом

```
let uri = 'http://localhost:[порт сервера]/items';
           this.axios.get(uri)
```

P.S. Я советую отказаться от использования axios и перейти на fetch.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]